# Принцип работы альтернативных методов авторизации

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, шифрование, пароль

Мне интересно как работают альтернативные методы авторизации вроде пин-кода и отпечатков пальца. Классический пример: менеджер паролей. Есть мастер-пароль - тут все ясно: данные шифруются каким-то шифром вроде AES-256, используя этот пароль. Но как тут применяются пин-коды и отпечатки? Это ведь совсем другая последовательность символов, которая не может расшифровать исходные данные.

P.S. Неохота лезть в исходники опенсорсных менеджеров паролей. Если можно просто примерный алгоритм, без кода.

Comment: Не совсем ясно, что именно вас интересует. Не могли бы вы привести пример приложения или более подробно описать свой вопрос?

Comment: @LEQADA Я довольно подробно описал вопрос. Любой нормальный менеджер паролей. Ну там lastpass например. Или даже в десятой винде тоже есть возможность входить с пин-кодом в дополнение к паролю учетной записи.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо путать пароль с ключом. Пароль/пин/отпечаток пальца лишь средство (причем не единственное) для генерации ключа. Использование пароля в качестве ключа - это извините, мягко говоря не принято.

В самом распространенном варианте делается через алгоритм [PBKDF2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (Password Based Key Derivation Function)

Можно заморочиться и покруче - как [например ребята из Яндекса](https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/344382/)